# Keras expected dense_13 to have 2 dimensions

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am getting very confusing error messages from Keras. I use the following model and pass to it input with shape `(num_examples, n, 1)`.

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(n,1), return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(units=n, activation='linear'))
    return model
```

I get this error message:
`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_16 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (11030, 50, 1)`.

But how is that possible? If I use `model.summary()`, it shows that `LSTM` output has this shape: `(None, 64)`. So how would it pass array with shape `(11030, 50, 1)` to Dense layer?

Moreover, if I try to add `model.add(Flatten())` between LSTM and Dense, I get this error: `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_3: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2`.

So, it passes 2D to Flatten, but how it then possible that it passes 3D to Dense?

Comment: Try `input_shape=(None,n)`
About `flatten`, you need to `return_sequences` as `true`

Comment: I've just tried both: it still gives the same error. For some reason, it seems that input of shape `(11030, 50, 1)` goes directly to Dense. While the LSTM output of shape `(None, 64)` is supposed to go there instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not your model but the **targets**, i.e. the *y* labels you give. You have a mismatch because your model outputs `(batch_size, n)` and you are giving `(batch_size, 50, 1)`.

Assuming `n=50` then you need to squeeze your target labels to 2 dimensions and remove that 1. `y_train = y_train.squeeze()` should solve the shape mismatch.

Comment: Oh, indeed, you are right! It was autoencoder, so I was passing X_train both to input and target. Did not realize that they have to be different shapes!

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpful

```
import numpy as np
input_array = np.array(input_array).reshape(dim1, dim2)
```

where dim1, dim2 means size of dimension which are you need.

Comment: I know how to reshape it. The problems are: 1. If I reshape it to 2D then it will not be suitable for LSTM layer (that expects 3D). 2. 3D data should not even arrive to Dense layer, and I don't understand why it does (because LSTM output shape is (None, 64), so it is NOT 3D).