# LSTM inputs shape and output

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am new in this field. I try to use two inputs: price and sentiment to predict the next hour's price. After searching I found there is a tutorial, and here is the def:

```
import keras
def buildModel(dataLength, labelLength):
    price = Input(shape = (dataLength,1),name='price')
    sentiment = Input(shape=(dataLength,1),name='sentiment')

    priceLayers = LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)(price)
    sentimentLayers = LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)(sentiment)

    output = keras.layers.concatenate(
        [
            priceLayers,
            sentimentLayers,
        ]
    )
    output = Dense(labelLength, activation='linear',name='output')(output)

    model = Model(
        inputs = [
            price,
            sentiment
        ],
        outputs=[
            output
        ]
    )
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse')
    return model
```

the shape of my two inputs are: 
`trainX = (1, 22234, 51)` `trainS = (1, 22285, 1)`

I execute the def:

```
lstm = buildModel(22234,1)
lstm.fit([trainX,trainS],[trainX],validation_data=(
        [testX,testS],
        [testX]),epochs = 10
)
```

But I get `Error when checking input: expected price to have shape (22234, 1) but got array with shape (22234, 51)`

Actually, I am very confused about the shape, so my questions are:

1. How can I fix the error
2. For my trainX and trainS, their shapes are initial (22234, 51) and (22285, 1), but since input has to be 3D, and I found a tutorial says input_shape is (2,10) --> (batch_size, 2, 10). Therefore I reshape my input into (1,22234, 51) and (1,22285, 1) as batch size = 1. In this step am I correct? And how should I decide the batch size?

3.
In the `lstm.fit`, I have no idea of what output should I put, so is the place that I mark bold correct?

```
 lstm.fit([trainX,trainS],**[trainX]**,validation_data=(
            [testX,testS],
            **[testX]**),epochs = 10
    )
```

Comment: you should change the `buildModel` function with `price=Input(shape=(dataLength,54),name='price')

Comment: After I change it, I get another error... Error when checking target: expected output to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 22234, 51)

Comment: Then change it again to `shape=(1, dataLength, 51)`

Comment: If I change the shape like this, it will have error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_29: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
I saw someone says add 'return_sequences=False' in the first layer but in the def, there is already has return_sequences=False

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162609/keras-expected-dense-13-to-have-2-dimensions) help?